# should django password validation not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to build a vanilla user registration system with django using a custom registration_form. I would like to check that the password is correct without reloading the page. I am struggling both to require the passwords to comply with the standard set of django password requirements, as well as check that the two passwords match. What I want to achieve is to have the password fields behave like the email field. In the email field, if the @ symbol is missing, a popup appears telling me it needs to change. However, if the passwords don't match or are very few characters, I am still able to submit the form. Is this the expected behavior or is something going wrong? I know that I can check if the form is valid without reloading (e.g. using ajax to do an is_valid() check on the form) after it has been submitted but I am trying to figure out if this is necessary?

here is my form

```
class registration_form(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-field w-input", 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    email = forms.Field(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "form-field w-input", 'placeholder': 'Email address'}))
    password1 = forms.Field(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': "form-field w-input", 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.Field(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': "form-field w-input", 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)
```

Here is the relevant part of my template

```
<form action="{%url 'signup' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ registration_form.non_field_errors }}

        {{ registration_form.source.errors }}
        {{ registration_form.source }}
        <div class="div-block-register-text">
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ registration_form.username.errors }}
                
                {{ registration_form.username}}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ registration_form.email.errors }}
                {{ registration_form.email}}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ registration_form.password1.errors }}
                {{ registration_form.password1}}
            </div>  
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ registration_form.password2.errors }}
                {{ registration_form.password2}}
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is the relevant part of the view

```
class CustomLoginView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        
        context = {'registration_form': registration_form,
                   'login_form':AuthenticationForm}
        template = 'homepage/login-register.html'
        return render(request,template,context=context)
```

Comment: im pretty sure you dont get this feature built in ... you need to validate it yourself using js or on post using python

Comment: I think validating if the password is too short or something like that is unnecessary. You just need to check if the password matches the user's stored password

Comment: bichanna this is for registration rather than logging them in :). Thanks Joran that would explain my difficulty!